# Custom loop pagination links not working

Tags: posts, customization, pagination, links

I'm bringing up an issue that could not be solved after googling for solutions over a few days. The goal I have to meet is to output a pagination for a custom post type named office-magazines with working links. I already managed to output the pagination but clicking any of the links within it takes me to the top page.

Here's the code I embedded into the page template:

```
   <?php
        global $wp_query, $paged;
        $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

        $args = array(
          'post_type' => 'office-magazines',
          'posts_per_page' => 9,
          'paged'          => $paged,
          'has_archieve'  => true
        );

        $catquery = new WP_Query($args);
   ?>

   <p class="pagination">
    <?php echo custom_pagination_bar( $loop ); ?>
  </p>
```

Passing `'post_type' => 'office-magazines'` is meant to filter out all posts apart from the ones belonging to the custom post type, `'office-magazines'`.

Using the next code in functions.php, I intended to define the function of the pagination:

```
function custom_pagination_bar($custom_loop) {
  $big = 999999999;
 echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link( $big ) ),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total' => $custom_loop->max_num_pages
) );
}
```

The same code works for the main post pagination which is output in a separate template page but fails for the custom post pagination.

Could someone please help me find a solution to getting the custom post pagination links to work?

Hoping for some advice,

Ead

Comment: Any reason you're using a custom query and not the main loop?

Comment: the variable you are passing is wrong here.. it should be  $catquery
<?php echo custom_pagination_bar( $catquery ); ?>

Comment: Indeed, I did not have to resort using the custom query: I managed to filter the main query for the custom post type in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => '[custom post type name]',
  'paged' => $paged,
  'has_archieve' => true    
);
$catquery = new WP_Query($args);    
echo pagination_bar($catquery);
```

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that worked for me happens to add an action filter to functions.php in the following format:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', function($q){
    if (is_category()){
        if(is_category('NEWS')):
            $q->set( 'posts_per_page', 2 );
        endif;
    }
});
```

Comment: You can delete first `is_category()`.

Comment: The code pasted above was set to be expanded for other category pages and a standard category page, hence having the extra is_category().